# how to make list with for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, for-loop, bootstrap-5

I tried to made a list with a for Loop and now I'm stuck because the program isn't showing any error but is not building any list elements. Can somebody explain why and how?

It seems that it can read the value of the input element which I thought don`t seems to be the problem, so I was thinking that it must be the problem with reading it from the array. But I am just a beginner so when someone knows the actual solution to the problem, I would appreciate it.

```
let array = [];

function buildList() {
  let ul = document.getElementById("prototype_List");
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let list = document.createElement("li");
    list.innerText = array[i];
    let setting =  document.getElementById("prototype_List");
    setting.append(list);
  }
}

function Name_Tag() {
  let checkName = document.getElementById("textfeld").value;
  
  if(checkName.length === 0) {
    alert("write Name");
  } else {
    array.push(checkName);
    buildList();
  }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <button onclick="Name_Tag" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">ADD Name</button>
          <input id="textfeld" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
        </div>
        <ul id="prototype_List">
          
        </ul>
          
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `onclick="Name_Tag"` to `onclick="Name_Tag()"`

Comment: Thanks, a little emberased that i didnt notice it but that works